Как максимально быстро обнаружить пиксель в центре экрана на Java?
Какую библиотеку использовать чтобы реализовать поиск пикселя (определеного цвета) в центре экрана и если нашел нажать на ЛКМ. Мне нужна именно скорость обнаруживание пикселя и нажатие на ЛКМ как можно это реализовать ?

насколько я помню в java это реализуется без всяких библиотек, что касается скорости то если не делать анализ всего экрана это даст требуемую скорость https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java только задайте нужные размеры области

Этот вопрос похож на: Код на Java для узнавания цвета пикселей. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
